Physical interpretation of Inverse Square Model
Attempted to model the extreme work done in 2D by a force acting to obey  inverse square law which is so important in physics (Gravitation, electromagnetics, electrostatics, Coulomb's law of forces etc..) as below:
Seen as a maximizing function W without constraint in polar coordinates $  (r,\theta)$:
$$W= \int \frac{ds}{r^2} = \int \frac{\sqrt{r^2+ r^{'2}}}{r^2}d \theta$$
Using Euler Lagrange equation (with Beltrami special case first integral when Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on $\theta$) we have
$$\frac{{\sqrt{r^2+ r^{'2}}}}{r^2} -\frac{r'}{r^2}\frac{r'}{\sqrt{r^2+ r^{'2}}}  = c_1 $$
leading to the ode
$$ r^2+ r^{'2}= d^2$$
where $d$ is an arbitrary constant. It has solution as all circles diameter $d$ through the origin.
$$ r= d \cos(\theta + \alpha)$$
($\alpha$ arbitrary angles of circle rotation about origin)
However am unable to interpret what these lines are in any particular application/scenario.
Please make any comment to help in making possible representation of these lines that could be relevant to the Inverse Square Law in Physics.
(  post Transferred from StackExchange Math)


The geometry influences the model.  Point charges produce inverse square laws because they generate spherical "wave fronts" in 3D space.  Infinite line charges generate cylindrical wave fronts which look like ripples in a pond, which are 2D (i.e., inverse laws).  You are asking a 3D question and expecting a 2D answer.

Thinking of the Newton model for planetary motion as a 2Dproblem involving inverse square law. Is it incorrect?
